# How do I close the files from tempfile.mkstemp?

Tags: python, ulimit

On my machine Linux machine `ulimit -n` gives `1024`. This code:

```
from tempfile import mkstemp

for n in xrange(1024 + 1):
    f, path = mkstemp()
```

fails at the last line loop with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utest.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 300, in mkstemp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 235, in _mkstemp_inner
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/tmpc5W3CF'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
ImportError: No module named fileutils
```

It seems like I've opened to many files - but the `type` of `f` and `path` are simply `int` and `str` so I'm not sure how to close each file that I've opened. **How do I close the files from tempfile.mkstemp?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
import tempfile
import os
for idx in xrange(1024 + 1):
    outfd, outsock_path = tempfile.mkstemp()
    outsock = os.fdopen(outfd,'w')
    outsock.close()
```

Comment: Just to explain a bit.  mkstemp() returns a unix file descriptor, so you to work with it you need either open it using fdopen or use the os close function: os.close()

Answer (score 34):

Since `mkstemp()` returns a raw file descriptor, you can use [os.close()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.close):

```
import os
from tempfile import mkstemp

for n in xrange(1024 + 1):
    f, path = mkstemp()
    # Do something with 'f'...
    os.close(f)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`os.close()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.close) to close the file descriptor:

```
import os
from tempfile import mkstemp

# Open a file
fd, path = mkstemp()  

# Close opened file
os.close( fd )
```